# Add items to ngx-chips input model and only keep display and value fields

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel, ngx-chips

I'm using [ngx-chips](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) for a tag input control. I'm using my own custom objects as items to use in the control's dropdown; these have this structure:

```
_id: number;
name: string;
summary: string;
creationDate?: string;
lastUpdate?: string;
```

So as per ngx-chips documentation, I provide `[identifyBy]="'_id'"` and `[displayBy]="'name'"` as inputs to the control; now when I choose another item to add on the control and update the model, it gets added with all of its fields as listed above;

This is my input:

```
<tag-input [(ngModel)]="goalModel" [theme]="'wsm-theme'" [identifyBy]="'_id'" [displayBy]="'name'" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true" [placeholder]="'Add filters'" class="wsm-input px-1 py-0">
     <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
                         [autocompleteItems]="goalFilters"
                         [limitItemsTo]="4"
                         [identifyBy]="'_id'" [displayBy]="'name'">
     </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>
```

Is there some way to upon adding the item to only keep the `_id` and `name` fields on the model? I'm thinking it should be something done in the `(onAdd)` output event of the control; but I can't think of a way to actually make this happen, if it can be done at all.

Comment: Are the other properties `summary`, `creationDate`, and `lastUpdate` used anywhere on your component?

Comment: Not on this component specifically, I may use them on a different one, but I just make a request to fetch all that data; for this component I only need `name` and `id`